# requireJS: Porting C++ classes, don't want to state class name twice

Tags: javascript, c++, requirejs

I'm porting a C++ project to Javascript. I'd like to keep the object-oriented design, so I decided to use requireJS to organize the ported classes as modules.
I simulate inheritance like this:

```
define(
[
],

function()
{
    'use strict';

    function Base( arguments )
    {
    }

    function Inherited( arguments )
    {
        Base.call( this, arguments );
    }

    Inherited.prototype = Object.create( Base.prototype );

    return {
                Inherited   : Inherited
            };
});
```

Let's say I save this module to a file 'inherited.js' and require it in another module:

```
define(
[
    'inherited'
],

function( Inherited )
{
    'use strict';

    function Whatever( arguments )
    {
        var inherited = new Inherited.Inherited( arguments );
    }

    return {
                Whatever    : Whatever,
            };
});
```

What bothers me now is that I have to state the class name twice at object creation, once as the module name and once for the name of the function/class.

Instead, I'd like to be able to call:

```
var inherited = new Inherited( arguments );
```

I can achieve this by returning an anonymous function in 'inherited.js' but then I can't define the inheritance dependency anymore.

I realize that the idea behind modules is to prevent pollution of the global namespace - keep in mind that the code posted above is only used within my library which is wrapped in a a single module before being used in the actual application.

So to instantiate the function/class *Inheritated* I'd have to type *Library.Inherited.Inherited* but I'd prefer *Library.Inherited*.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the Inherited constructor function:

```
define(function () {
  function Inherited() {
  }

  Inherited.prototype = {
  };

  return Inherited;
});
```

Module export values can be returnable type.